# API from OPENWEATHER, not acquiring the precipitation using pyowm

Tags: python

I am having the following problem with pyown:

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('API_number')
obs = owm.weather_at_place('Sao Paulo')
w = obs.get_weather()
rain_dict = w.get_rain()
rain = [rain_dict.get(k) for k in ['3h']]
print rain
```

When I check the value of rain it returns [Nope], when I check the pure data from rain_dict it returns {} and the normal is {'3h':'some value'}.

Is any problem from Open Weather or from PyOwm?

Comment: So... it returns Nope? :D Try debugging and seeing whether internals of obs used manually with API are returning what you need.

Comment: ...did you mean `None`? That's the default return from `dict.get` when the key is missing.

Comment: Rain returns [Nope], you are right. But when I try to check rain_dict is not returning anything, only a empty dict -> {}

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is no longer a problem for you, but for others that may be experiencing the same issue, here is what I found. if no rain has fallen the dictionary that is returned will be {}, vice {'1h' : '0.0', '3h' : '0.0}.

The easy way around this is to check for the dictionary slot (e.g. '1h'), and if it is true then assign the value of that slot to your variable as below

```
if '1h' in rain_dict:

    rain = rain_dict['1h']

else:

    rain = 0.0

print(rain)
```

In my working through getting the values for rainfall I have come across a few issues. First, when I pull the rain dictionary I only get the '1h' rainfall amounts, there is no '3h' total. Second, the interval for the '1h' rainfall amount is a little weird. I have not seen reliable data from this. For instance, i will pull the value when I know it has rained in the last hour. Sometimes it shows an accumulated rainfall and other times not. I was thinking initially that these values are only for the hour block (i.e. from 6:00pm to 6:59 pm) and not from the last 60 minutes (i.e. polled at 6:24pm the rainfall amount is from 5:24pm to 6:24pm). I will be looking into this more to gain better resolution on this issue, and will provide an update once I have something definitive. On a side note I did check the OPENWEATHER 2.5 API, but did not find any description of what the rain object truly returns.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I ran an experiment the other day, when I knew it was going to rain. And I found some disparity in the data I received. I used the following two methods to pull the rainfall data:

```
weather = mgr.weather_at_coords(location['lat'], location['lon']).weather
new_rainfall = weather.rain
```

The other option was:

```
current = mgr.one_call(location['lat'], location['lon']).current
new_rainfall = current.rain
```

The data using these two methods was not the same, although it was somewhat similar. But more importantly, to me it doesn't seem to actually show accurate data, in that at one time the hourly rainfall value returned {}, indicating no rain. Then five minutes later I received a value of 0.42 mm, but then five minutes later i recieved only {} responses (see example below).

```
2020-09-13 11:05:00, {}
2020-09-13 11:10:00, {'1h': 0.42}
2020-09-13 11:15:00, {}
2020-09-13 11:20:00, {}
2020-09-13 11:25:00, {}
2020-09-13 11:30:00, {}
2020-09-13 11:35:00, {}
2020-09-13 11:40:00, {}
```

I have submitted a support request to the Open Weather Map API folks, and I am awaiting a response. In the meantime, I believe I have found a more accurate way of polling for the last hour's rainfall using one_call_history:

```
now = int(time())
then = now - 3600

history = mgr.one_call_history(location['lat'], location['lon'], then).current
new_rainfall = history.rain
```

I will update further if I do receive any useful information from OWM, but at this point it seems that using the first two methods reports the instantaneous rainfall rate * 1 hour.

Stay Tuned ...

Comment: Hey, can you please share with us your final verdict ?
I'm trying to fetch the hourly rain and snow data and I ran into the same problems.

Comment: I have received an inadequate response from OWM, but in utilizing these methods more I believe that there is no real issue. I have found when the rainfall amounts are just trace amounts (e.g. < 2 mm) the reported rainfalls are inconsistent (as described), but for rainfalls more substantial the reported values are more consistent.